# How can I change the last download location in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, gtk, qt

Applications like `simple-scan` uses one kind of a file-dialog (A) and applications like `chromium`, `telegram`, `xfce4-screenshooter` use some other kind of file-dialog (B). (There are two different kinds of file-dialog in my system. Side question: Can I unify those?)

They all start the suggested download/save folder from where the previous application left. (An application that uses group A continues from where the previous application that uses group A left)

I want to control the starting point of the dialog, maybe by setting an environment variable or changing a file's contents.

Is that possible?

System: XFCE, Debian Buster

Comment: Download location is normally set in your browser. Set that to what you want. If other apps save files from the Internet, you need to set those apps as well.

Comment: No, the other applications have nothing to do with internet. One of them is a Printer/scanner application, the other is Screenshot application. They are both offline applications. So, there has to be a way to configure that behavior within a registry setting or somewhere like that.

Comment: These apps need to be set individually for saving. That is how it works for me - Windows and Linux both.